# Linux Symbolic Link to USB device not working

Tags: symlink, udev, ftdi

On my Raspberry Pi I am trying to create a symbolic link for a device plugged into the USB port. I have done this before and it worked just fine, but recently I re-flashed the Pi's SD card to start from a clean slate again and now the Symbolic link does not work. I can see it in (/dev/GPS), but when I go to use it nothing happens. To the best of my knowledge I have set it up in exactly the same way. More info on the setup below.

The device in question: Its a Ublox 6M GPS connected to the PI's USB via an FTDI. Because the Pi can assign the FTDI to either /dev/ttyUSB0 or /dev/ttyUSB1 as it sees fit at boot, I need to assign it a symbolic link so my program can always find it irrespoective of what name the OS wants to give it.

So I followed the instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-bind-usb-device-under-a-static-name) to set up the symbolic link. I added the following line to /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules.

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", SYMLINK+="GPS"
```

These are the same instructions I followed originally (pre SD card re-flash) and they worked just fine, but now it doesn't work. I have tested the GPS/FTDI by using its OS assigned name and I can get GPS data out, but when I use my symbolic link name it does't work. So that is where the problem seems to be. I've triple checked the idVendor and idProduct values for the FTDI using

```
 udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0)
```

Any ideas? Alternative solutions are welcome.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Have you ensured that the user accessing the device has read/write permissions to the port and usb controller?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a solution, but not the answer to the specific question. I still don't know why the above it not working, but I have found that I don't need to create my own symbolic links. The system creates is own in /dev/serial/by-id/. These seem to be working OK for me.

Comment: Generally these updates go as edits or comments to the original question.